# Collision code not working

Tags: java, collision

I have these 'monsters' that are continually created and deleted when they reach the bottom of the screen. They move left and right and I want it so that when they touch (or if they are created ontop of eachother) one of them moves out of the way.

Currently I have in the class managing the monsters:

```
public void update() {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < (Constants.NUMBER_ENEMIES-2)) {
        if (Rect.intersects(npcManager.getList().get(i).getRectangle(), npcManager.getList().get(i + 1).getRectangle()))
            npcManager.getList().get(i).setRectangle(200);
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Where npcManager is an instance and thelist it gets us an array list of the NPCs. The setRectangle method I created is:

```
public Rect setRectangle(int move) {
    rectangle.top += move;
    rectangle.bottom += move;
    return rectangle;
}
```

Where it should move the NPC down by 200 so that it is no longer colliding.

My question is, is there any reason why this code isn't working? Currently the rectangles just pass through eachtother and the code has no effect.

Comment: You are just checking if a rectangle collides with the next one in the list (`i`, `i+1`): what happens if the first rectangle collides with the last one?

Comment: Probably because of a bug somewhere in the code you are not showing? Try creating a [mcve]; or learn to use a debugger. We cant help with such input.

Comment: @backslash there are currently only two items in the list, just wanted to keep it simple whilst checking - I should have clarified that sorry

Comment: @George Then are you sure the two rectangles really collides? You could use a debugger to check the values of the rectangle (or just print the rectangle and see), Then do manual calculations to check if they really intersect

Comment: @ghostcat if there's anything missing that's needed I apologise but this is the only code that's been added and associated in the function I'm trying to do, everything else is still working as should even with this added.

Comment: @backslash I'm running the application in an emulator and they collide, but instead of moving they just pass though each other with no change

Comment: @George As I said, you should check values. What you see with your eyes isn't necessarily equal to what happens in the program. The fact that you see a collision doesn't mean their values collide. For example, even if you see a picture colliding with another, the rectangles could have width=0 and height=0, so they'll never collide. Check those values and you'll see if the problem lies there.

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure what is in that Rect class; and if that matters. Minimal but *complete*, as the link says: [mcve]

Comment: @ghostcat The Rect class is a class in android developer, it is just the general class for using rectangles.   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html

Comment: @backslash the rectangles are definitely there and definitely passing through each other as non-zero width/height objects, can I ask is there anything wrong with the code itself? Am I allowed to set the rectangle values in that way?

Comment: @George post the values in the question. The code itself doesn't seem to be wrong, but posting the values will help us understand if the problem is there and why

Comment: @BackSlash I'm sorry I just found the problem and realised that the loop was never initiating due to a change I made before. Thank you for staying to help though, doing the checks has definitely given me a useful tool for future use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the number of enemies - 2 (when the number of enemies in this specific case was 2), the while loop never initiated and the code did not run.

Comment: @GhostCat The question was viewed by over 50 people and upvoted, I believe it's better to show the solution than leave people in the dark. Also, if you read the comments the number of enemies is given in my first response. Please don't be so toxic.

Comment: Sure. Your choice.